# Problem with value arguments in const fn with basic numeric generics

Tags: rust

I'm trying to translate some of my C++ code into Rust and came across the following problem. The code is simplified to a (hopefully) minimal not-working example. In the end it is supposed to work with all unsigned integer types, but for this example it just needs to implement the `PartialOrd` trait.

```rust
#![allow(incomplete_features)]  
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![feature(const_trait_impl)]   


const fn foo<T>(n: T, k: T) -> T                                       
where                                                                   
    T: Sized,                                                           
    T: Copy,
    T: ~const core::marker::Destruct,
    T: ~const std::cmp::PartialOrd,                            
{                                                                       
    if n < k {                                                          
        n
    } else {
        k
    }
}
```

Fails to compile with the following error message:

```
error[E0658]: cannot borrow here, since the borrowed element may contain interior mutability
 13 |     if n < k {                                                          
    |        ^
```

If I replace the arguments `n` and `k` with references, it compiles. Turns out, the functions in the `PartialOrd` are also implemented using references. So from my understanding, the expression `2 < 4` will call the `le` function with references. For performance reasons, I doubt that's what's happening, though.

It's actually two questions that I'm asking:

1. Can I solve the error without using references?
2. Why is `PartialOrd` using references while `Ord` uses values (at least for `min` and `max`, but not for `cmp`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Adding `#![feature(const_refs_to_cell)]` makes it compile.
2. `min` and `max` take `Self` because they return one of the two arguments as `Self`. Other methods in `Ord` and `PartialOrd` else returns a `bool` or an `Ordering` so they can take by reference. if `min` and `max` they took by reference the signature would be `fn max<'a>(&'a self, other: &'a Self) -> &'a Self` which you "get for free" because there is a `impl<A> Ord for &A where A: Ord`.